# Remove query string from URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to make the following redirection using .htaccess.

Redirect this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?something@gmail.com
```

To this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?something
```

So basically all I want is to remove `@gmail.com` from the query string whenever is presented while keeping everything else.

I tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)@gmail.com$
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1%2? [R=permanent]
```

Unfortunately didn't work even after doing multiple tweaks. What is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please do provide details like uri `something@gmail.com` should be taken care by which file in backend? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. The processing page is index.php. So the URL is like this:
http://website.com/index.php?something@gmail.com
I need to remove @gmail.com whenever presented. So it should always be redirected to:
http://website.com/index.php?something

Comment: This make sense, please do update your question with same details, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Please make sure that htacces and index.php files are on root folder at same level.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Redirect rules to get index.php?something in browser here.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(index\.php)\?([^@]*)@.*\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?%2 [R=301,L]
```